# how to draw with matlab two seprate graphs with loglog?

Tags: matlab, factorial, loglog

i am trieng to draw with matlab the two functions  :

`y1=ln(n!)` and `y2=ln(n)*n` 
when n is a vector like this : `n=1:100`
i want to draw both of these functions in the same graph , and then draw another function : `((y2-y1)/y1)` on a different graph .. i did the following but it only shows me the first graph with only one function , any help of what i am doing wrong ? thanks.

```
n=1:100;
format long
n_factorial=factorial(n);
y1 =log(n_factorial);
figure;
loglog(n,y1,'b');
hold on;
y2=(n*(log(n)'));
loglog(n,y2,'r');

y3=((y2-y1)/y1);
loglog(n,y3);
```

Comment: Reposting since I forgot to escape out `*` verus `.*` but basically this is your issue, nothing to do with the plotting, you need to understand the difference between matrix multiplication and element-wise multiplication in Matlab: uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html and uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html

Comment: but i did that and i still get one graph :/

Comment: When you say different graphs, do you mean within the same figure? If so, check out the function `subplot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two different method you can use to draw multiple graphs.

If you want to draw the two different graph on two different window, you should add the line :

```
figure;
```

each time you want to plot on a new window. 
In your code, you should now have

```
figure;
loglog(n,y1,'b'); hold on;
loglog(n,y2,'r');

figure;
loglog(n,y3);
```

If you want to draw two different graph on the same 'figure', you should use the command subplot, like that:

```
subplot(2,1,1);
loglog(n,y1,'b'); hold on;
loglog(n,y2,'r');

subplot(2,1,2);
loglog(n,y3);
```

which basically divide your window's area between 2 lines and one row, and give to each position an index (in this case, 1 & 2) that you specify with the third parameter of the subplot command.

Also, I think there is a mistake in the code you posted for the dimensions of your vectors. You should verify what you wanna plot.